# What is the workflow for cutting stock problem?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, linear-programming

I would appreciate any advice on how to start programming an un-optimized cutting stock problem for an array of values in vba and excel.

I have just finished another time optimization program but this has me stumped. I end the previous program with an array of quantities and lengths.

My array would be something like:

| Qty | Length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 780.5 |
| 1 | 780.5 |
| 1 | 995 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 1 | 1147 |
| 1 | 923.7 |
| 1 | 1851.3 |
| 1 | 976 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 1 | 979 |
| 1 | 918.7 |
| 1 | 1841.3 |
| 1 | 993 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 1 | 987 |
| 1 | 1611 |
| 1 | 1611 |
| 1 | 983 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 1 | 1307 |
| 1 | 896 |
| 1 | 896 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 1 | 896 |
| 1 | 896 |
| 2 | 876 |
| 1 | 896 |
| 1 | 896 |
| 2 | 876 |

And end up with an output something like:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1851.3 | 1841.3 |  |  |
| 1611 | 1611 |  |  |
| 1307 | 1147 | 995 |  |
| 993 | 987 | 983 | 979 |
| 976 | 923.7 | 918.7 | 896 |
| 896 | 896 | 896 | 896 |
| 896 | 876 | 876 | 876 |
| 876 | 876 | 876 | 876 |
| 876 | 876 | 876 | 876 |
| 876 | 876 | 876 | 876 |
| 876 | 876 | 876 | 876 |
| 876 | 780.5 | 780.5 |  |

(The maximum length of aluminium profile I'm trying to cut is 4000mm)

If I could get a general rundown of the workflow for this I could keep working on it.

EDIT: I have figured out a way to have the array act like a single item list, sorted from highest to lowest (i.e. getting rid of the quantity column), so just need to get an idea of how the logic works for the actual organizational loop.

e.g. if I have a list like 1899, 1760, 1240, 1101, 900 and a max stock size of 4000, I don't think the algorithm would be too complex, I am just having trouble figuring out how the loop code would look in practical terms.

Comment: Check for similar questions on here - there are a couple.

Comment: I would google "cutting stock problem" to find references to algorithms. Not sure if it is wise to use VBA for this. Especially if you want to use some libraries or packages.